# building a CMAKE project (GNU Radio OOT blocks) in Qt editor

Tags: cmake, qt-creator, gnuradio

I want to build a CMAKE based project named GNU Radio (GR) in Qt Creator editor to be able to use its IDE features. I could build it in the Ubuntu terminal using cmake and make commands.

For more details, I am using GR:3.10.6, Ubuntu:22.04, UHD:4.3.0, Qt Creator:10.0.1. I've just added an OOT module and block and could successfully build and add it to the GR and it works well. To have a better graphical editor, I just want to develop in Qt editor (qtcreator). Specifically, I wonder what should be put in the .pro file to let me compile it there. Thanks in advance!

PS:
These items have been tested but not working:

```
LIBS += \
        -L/usr/local/lib/ -lgnuradio-tmo -lgnuradio-runtime -lgnuradio-blocks -lgnuradio-pmt -litpp
        -L/usr/local/include/gnuradio/
        -L/usr/local/include/tmo/
        -L/usr/local/include/pmt/
        -L/usr/local/include/uhd/
        -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
        -Llibfmt.so.8.1.1
        /usr/local/include/volk/ \
        /usr/include/ \
        /usr/include/python3.10/ \
       /usr/include/pybind11/ \
LIBS += -lgnuradio-pmt -lgnuradio-analog -lgnuradio-fft -lgnuradio-vocoder -lgnuradio-zeromq \
        -lvolk \
        -lgnuradio-blocks -lgnuradio-filter -lgnuradio-digital -lgnuradio-runtime -lgnuradio-fec \
```

Comment: Just open the CMakeLists.txt in Qt Creator. What happens if you try that?

Comment: Qt creator is using qmake...

Comment: Qt Creator has supported CMake for years. Use the latest version for best support, of course. I always recommend using the Qt Online installer, even if you just use it to install QT Creator and other tools, and want to use for example a Linux disto's own Qt libs and dev packages.

Comment: Also, I don't believe you when you say Qt Creator is using qmake, if you open CMakelists.txt in it.

Comment: I meant I am using the qmake mode in qt creator

Comment: Well, you should edit your question then, because it quite clearly says you are any to use cmake.